# Parse data off sport-reference using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python, in this project, I wanted to create a loop to parse all NFL teams' ranking data off https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/. I first created a data frame to be the directory, shown as below.

```
my_array = np.array([['crd','Arizona_Cardinals'],['atl','Atalanta_Falcons'],['rav','Baltimore_Ravens'],['buf','Buffalo_Bills'],
                  ['car','Carolina_Panthers'],['chi','Chicago_Bears'],['cin','Cincinnati_Bengals'],['cle','Cleveland_Browns'],
                  ['dal','Dalls_Cowboys'],['den','Denver_Broncos'],['det','Detroit_Lions'],['gnb','Green_Bay_Packers'],['htx','Houston_Texans'],
                  ['clt','Indianapolis_Colts'],['jax','Jacksonville_Jaguars'],['kan','Kansas_City_Chiefs'],['rai','Las_Vegas_Raiders'],
                  ['sgd','Los_Angeles_Chargers'],['ram','Los_Angeles_Rams'],['mia','Miami_Dolphins'],['min','Minnesota_Vikings'],
                  ['nwe','New_England_Patriots'],['nor','New_Orleans_Saints'],['nyg','New_York_Giants'],['nyj','New_York_Jets'],
                  ['phi','Philidophia_Eagles'],['pt','Pittsburgh_Steelers'],['sfo','San_Francisco_49ers'],['sea','Seattle_Seahawks'],
                  ['tam','Tampa_Bay_Buccaneers'],['oti','Tennessee_Titans'],['was','Washington_Football_Team']])

team_list = pd.DataFrame(my_array, columns=['code','teams'])
```

Here is the loop I used to parse all 32 webpages:

```
url_base = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/'
url_list = [url_base+str(i) for i in team_list['code']]
for url in url_list:
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = bs(page)

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    headers = []
    for i in table.find_all('th', scope = "col"):
        title=i.text.strip()
        headers.append(title)

    table_data = []
    for tr in table.find_all("tr"): 
        t_row = {}
        for td, th in zip(tr.find_all("td"), headers): 
            t_row[th] = td.text.replace('\n', '').strip()
    table_data.append(t_row)
```

However, the result turned out to be an empty list. Anything wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the logic without using `pandas`' `.read_html()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

my_array = np.array([['crd','Arizona_Cardinals'],['atl','Atlanta_Falcons'],['rav','Baltimore_Ravens'],['buf','Buffalo_Bills'],
                  ['car','Carolina_Panthers'],['chi','Chicago_Bears'],['cin','Cincinnati_Bengals'],['cle','Cleveland_Browns'],
                  ['dal','Dallas_Cowboys'],['den','Denver_Broncos'],['det','Detroit_Lions'],['gnb','Green_Bay_Packers'],['htx','Houston_Texans'],
                  ['clt','Indianapolis_Colts'],['jax','Jacksonville_Jaguars'],['kan','Kansas_City_Chiefs'],['rai','Las_Vegas_Raiders'],
                  ['sdg','Los_Angeles_Chargers'],['ram','Los_Angeles_Rams'],['mia','Miami_Dolphins'],['min','Minnesota_Vikings'],
                  ['nwe','New_England_Patriots'],['nor','New_Orleans_Saints'],['nyg','New_York_Giants'],['nyj','New_York_Jets'],
                  ['phi','Philadelphia_Eagles'],['pit','Pittsburgh_Steelers'],['sfo','San_Francisco_49ers'],['sea','Seattle_Seahawks'],
                  ['tam','Tampa_Bay_Buccaneers'],['oti','Tennessee_Titans'],['was','Washington_Football_Team']])



url_base = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/'
url_list = [(url_base+str(i[0]), i[1]) for i in my_array]
rows = []
for url, team in url_list:
    print('Gathering: %s' %team)
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    table = soup.find('table', {'id':'team_index'})
    headers = [x.text.strip() for x in table.find_all('tr')[1].find_all('th')]
    
    trs = table.find_all('tr')[2:]
    
    for tr in trs:
        year = tr.find('th').text.strip()
        if year == 'Year' or year == '':
            continue
        data = [year] + [x.text.strip() for x in tr.find_all('td')]
        
        rows.append(data)
        
final_table = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to fix the indentation and define `table_data` outside the loop

```
url_base = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/'
url_list = [url_base+str(i) for i in team_list['code']]

table_data = []
for url in url_list:
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = bs(page)

    for table in soup.find_all('table'):
        headers = []
        for i in table.find_all('th', scope = "col"):
            title=i.text.strip()
            headers.append(title)
        for tr in table.find_all("tr"): 
            t_row = {}
            for td, th in zip(tr.find_all("td"), headers): 
                t_row[th] = td.text.replace('\n', '').strip()
        table_data.append(t_row)
```

Comment: Thanks! But that also didn't work, it only gave me 28 teams' data, and each team only has one row.

Answer (score 0):

Few things wrong with the code:

First (as already mentioned), your indentation is off here, so you need to fix that. You want to parse the tables within that first loop when you create the soup object. Secondly, `zip` here returns an object, you need to do something like `list(zip(x, y))` to do what you are trying to do which is iterate through it. Third, even doing that, when you do use zip here (to create your dictionary), you'll want to use the headers as the key, not as the value. Fourth, the headers are multiindexed, so they're not exactly going to line up when you do the zip with the `td`s. Fifth (again already mentioned), you need to initialize your `table_data` before the loop, otherwise it'll just overwrite itself during the iterations.

Lastly, consider using `pandas`' `.read_html()`. It uses beautifulsoup under the hood and can parse the tables for you, and then you just need to do minimal work in cleaning up the table.

Also, few errors in your array that I fixed (you could also just grab those hrefs and team names from `https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/` table, but how you hard coded it should work fine, and those links won't be changing anytime soon, if ever.):

1. `'Atalanta_Falcons'` -> `'Atlanta_Falcons'`
2. `'Dalls_Cowboys'` -> `'Dallas_Cowboys'`
3. `'Philidophia Eagles'` -> `'Philadelphia Eagles'`
4. `'sgd'`-> `'sdg'`
5. `'pt'` -> `'pit'`

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([['crd','Arizona_Cardinals'],['atl','Atlanta_Falcons'],['rav','Baltimore_Ravens'],['buf','Buffalo_Bills'],
                  ['car','Carolina_Panthers'],['chi','Chicago_Bears'],['cin','Cincinnati_Bengals'],['cle','Cleveland_Browns'],
                  ['dal','Dallas_Cowboys'],['den','Denver_Broncos'],['det','Detroit_Lions'],['gnb','Green_Bay_Packers'],['htx','Houston_Texans'],
                  ['clt','Indianapolis_Colts'],['jax','Jacksonville_Jaguars'],['kan','Kansas_City_Chiefs'],['rai','Las_Vegas_Raiders'],
                  ['sdg','Los_Angeles_Chargers'],['ram','Los_Angeles_Rams'],['mia','Miami_Dolphins'],['min','Minnesota_Vikings'],
                  ['nwe','New_England_Patriots'],['nor','New_Orleans_Saints'],['nyg','New_York_Giants'],['nyj','New_York_Jets'],
                  ['phi','Philadelphia_Eagles'],['pit','Pittsburgh_Steelers'],['sfo','San_Francisco_49ers'],['sea','Seattle_Seahawks'],
                  ['tam','Tampa_Bay_Buccaneers'],['oti','Tennessee_Titans'],['was','Washington_Football_Team']])


final_table = pd.DataFrame()
url_base = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/'
url_list = [(url_base+str(i[0]), i[1]) for i in my_array]
for url, team in url_list:
    print('Gathering: %s' %team)
    
    # Gets full unfiltered table
    table = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[0]
    
    #Drop those sub header rows
    table = table[table['Year'].ne('Year')]
    
    #Drop the null rows
    table = table.dropna(subset = ['Year'])
    
    # Append to your final dataframe
    final_table = final_table.append(table, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(final_table)
      Year   Lg                 Tm  W   L  ...    MoV   SoS    SRS  OSRS  DSRS
0     2021  NFL  Arizona Cardinals  0   0  ...    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN
1     2020  NFL  Arizona Cardinals  8   8  ...    2.7  -0.1    2.6   1.5   1.0
2     2019  NFL  Arizona Cardinals  5  10  ...   -5.1   1.8   -3.2  -0.3  -2.9
3     2018  NFL  Arizona Cardinals  3  13  ...  -12.5   1.0  -11.5  -9.6  -1.9
4     2017  NFL  Arizona Cardinals  8   8  ...   -4.1   0.4   -3.7  -4.0   0.2
   ...  ...                ... ..  ..  ...    ...   ...    ...   ...   ...
2089  1936  NFL   Boston Redskins*  7   5  ...    3.3  -3.0    0.3  -1.0   1.3
2090  1935  NFL    Boston Redskins  2   8  ...   -5.3  -0.8   -6.1  -6.1   0.0
2091  1934  NFL    Boston Redskins  6   6  ...    1.1  -0.8    0.2  -1.7   2.0
2092  1933  NFL    Boston Redskins  5   5  ...    0.5   1.4    1.9  -0.8   2.7
2093  1932  NFL      Boston Braves  4   4  ...   -2.4  -1.6   -4.0  -4.0  -0.1

[2094 rows x 29 columns]
```

Comment: Omg, I didn't realize that I had so many typos. Thank you so much for picking them out! And you even solved the year problem, which I wasn't able to figure out! I don't think I am allowed to use read_html() for this project (I’m doing boot camp, and they have certain requirements), but really great example of using it. I will definitely try that out for another website!

Comment: Ah ok. I’ll provide a non read_html solution tomorrow then.

Comment: That's very nice of you! Thank you!

Comment: I provided a non read html. Make sure to accept the solution too